# Using different skins for different rows in a List

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a `fl.controls.List` that I am populating with values. I would like certain rows to be of a different color. For example, either red or green.

Is there a way of specifying that a particular row should use a particular skin?

I have the skins imported into my project inside a swc and so they can be easily accessed. I'm having trouble finding any reference to a particular row of a list though.

Comment: In some instances in Flex (I know you're not using it) I've seen properties for a function that in turn returns an item renderer class to be used given a particular data element, however I don't think this exists in the Flash base UI controls.  However within the skin definition itself you should be able to modify what is shown based on the data property (more of a Flex guy so I know this methodology works there not so sure in normal Flash IDE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create a custom `CellRenderer` class that overrides the `onDrawBackground` method.

You then can set the cell renderer by doing `list.setStyle('cellRenderer', MyCellRenderer)`